# SwiftUI menu with failing trailing closure (MenuStyleConfiguration)

Tags: ios, xcode, menu, swiftui, closures

I am creating an iOS application with SwiftUI

I used the master/detail template and got to this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
  
     NavigationView {
        
        if (conditionsForMasterDetail)
        {
          masterView
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Master"))
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: EditButton(),
                trailing: Button(
                    action: {
                        withAnimation { self.dates.insert(Date(), at: 0) }
                    }
                ) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            )
        }
        
        if (conditionsForDetaiView)
        {
          detailView
        }
        } //NavigationView
    .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle()).toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
            Menu
            { //error here: “Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'MenuStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure”                        
                    NavigationLink(destination:HelpView(appData: appData))
                                        {                        Button(action: {}) {
                        Label(help_menu_item, systemImage: "")
                    }
                    }
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Label(liability_disclaimer_menu_item, systemImage: "")
                    }
                
                                       Button(action: {}) {
                        Label(R.string.about_menu_item, systemImage: "")
                    }
                    

                
                
            }//menu
             
                 label: {//error here: Extra argument 'label' in call
        Label("Menu", systemImage: "")
    }
         
    }//toolbar item
         
           
}//toolbar

} //body
} //ContentView
```

The problem is the menu, because an error is issued:

```
Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'MenuStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure
```

Note that the trailing closure is just a different way to write parameters of an initializers. Menu seems to accept a configuration but I see the content and the label (error on label: Extra argument 'label' in call).

I tried all kind of writing the init without the trailing closure syntax but it does not lead to working code.

I would like to know if it is a bug or it is a real error.

Comment: In SwiftUI views are structs *not* classes.

Comment: @pawello2222 They can also be final class. What can you say about the error?

Comment: @P5music, No they cannot. Even if you compile it just by conformance to protocol (it is allowed by swift language, not SwiftUI contract), but SwiftUI run-time will generate you exception **Fatal error: views must be value types**.

Comment: @Asperi I cannot believe my entire app is garbage now. I do not modify the Views so SwiftUI should not be worried. Is there any chances that after compiling the app doesn't crashes if it respects the SwiftUI principles?

Comment: @Asperi I am trying to change my code to have structs for Views, but the trailing closures is failing for whatever reason that is not related to the View, please can you understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is somehow cleaned replicated your snapshot that compiled well with Xcode 12 / iOS 14. You can inject your specifics back one by one.

*Note: `Button` in `NavigationLink` does not work and so has no sense (because `NavigationLink` is a button itself)*

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var conditionsForMasterDetail = false
    @State private var conditionsForDetaiView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if (conditionsForMasterDetail)
            {
                Text("masterView")
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Master"))
                    .navigationBarItems(
                        leading: EditButton(),
                        trailing: Button(
                            action: {
                                withAnimation { /*self.dates.insert(Date(), at: 0)*/ }
                            }
                        ) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                    )
            }

            if (conditionsForDetaiView)
            {
                Text("detailView")
            }
        } //NavigationView
        .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle()).toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                Menu
                {
                    NavigationLink(destination:Text("HelpView(appData: appData)"))
                    { Text("Link")
                        //                        Label(help_menu_item, systemImage: "")
                    }
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Text("A")
                        //                        Label(liability_disclaimer_menu_item, systemImage: "")
                    }

                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Text("B")
                        //                        Label(R.string.about_menu_item, systemImage: "")
                    }
                }//menu

                label: {//error here: Extra argument 'label' in call
                    Label("Menu", systemImage: "")
                }
            }//toolbar item
        }//toolbar
    } //body
} //ContentView
```

Comment: you were right, I edited the question. The error is there however. What you can say about it?

Comment: Inside some menu entries there were calls with closures that were wrong as to their syntax/parameters/brakets. It was too much for Xcode

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't specifically answer this question but because I couldn't find any other answers to this topic.

Throws the same error:

```
struct TextPopup: View {
    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            Text("hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Compiles correctly:

```
struct TextPopup: View {
    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            Text("hello")
        } label: {}
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add string to the `Menu`, e.g. `Menu("menu") { ... }`